# Conditionally assign variable if function returns a value

Tags: php, undefined, return-value

I've been out of PHP programming for a while, but I'm almost sure I used to be able to write something like the following:

```
function checkData($data, $moreData) {
    if ($foo != validate($data)) {
        return false;
    }
    if ($bar != validate($moreData)) {
        return false;
    }
    $result = "$foo" . "$bar";
    return $result;
}
```

...where "$foo" and "$bar" haven't been set yet and where the "validate()" function either returns validated data, or returns false if validation fails.

I can't figure out where I'm going wrong, but that code (and variations of it) is throwing an "Undefined variable" error for $myVar.

What would be the correct syntax for this concept?

Comment: $myVar?  You mean $result?  So how do you test $foo != X when $foo hasn't been set yet?  Maybe you are thinking of if( $foo = validate($data) ) { return false; } where validate() returns true or false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you meant a little bit different thing. Instead of

```
if ($foo != validate($data)) {
```

You've been using this

```
if (!$foo = validate($data)) {
```

What is happening there is:
1. Call validate function
2. Assign the result to variable
3. Check if condition for that variable.
It's kind of the same as

```
$foo = validate($data)
if(!$foo)
```

But as you can understand it's not recommended way of doing the things as it's hard to read and needs explanation(otherwise why do u ask it here, hehe)

Answer (score 0):

PHP has become more strict over the years. You should always instantiate your variables. The following modifications should resolve your "undefined variable" issues:

```
function checkData($data, $moreData) {
    $foo = $bar = null;
    if (!$foo = validate($data)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (!$bar = validate($moreData)) {
        return false;
    }
    $result = "$foo" . "$bar";
    return $result;
}
```

It isn't the conditional that is throwing the warning, but where you attempt to assign the non-existent variables to `$result`. Additionally, your conditionals are checking for comparison rather than assignment.